# Provide potentional nil variable to function in GOLANG

Tags: go

I want to call a function with a int variable that can have a value or can be nil. In the main function i'm doing this call.

```
doDomething(10) // does not work?
doDomething(nil) // works

func doSomething(parent_id *int) {
    fmt.Print(parent_id)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> cannot use a (type int) as type *int in argument to doSomething

I use the *int pointer, therefore the nil works but not if it is a value. Then I'm getting the type mismatch.

Comment: What is your problem ? Provide the error message if one or describe the expected and actual result.

Comment: I just added the error description, thanks

Comment: You can't pass an `int` as an `*int`. You're also going to have a problem using an `*int` as a `string` in the `Printf` call.

Comment: There simply are no nil ints in Go. It might be worth peeking at the language spec for such basics.

Answer (score 8):

`doSomething` expects a `*int`parameter. `10` is of type `int`, so this is he source of the error.

This is a valid usage:

```
 i := 10
 doDomething(&i)
```

This is how `doSomething` should look like:

```
func doSomething(parent_id *int) {
    if parent_id == nil{
        //nil
        fmt.Println("nil")
        return
    } 
    //valid int 
    fmt.Printf("%d", *parent_id)
}
```

Comment: But if I then have 1:= nil i'm still getting the error. The value is a int or nil

Comment: I don't understand, you can use either this syntax to pass a real int or call `doSomething(nil)`

Comment: @aureliar Can you expand your answer to show how to use `*int` and validate if it's `nil` or int?

Comment: @OscarRyz Edited the answer